# How would you evaluate $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{\sqrt{2n+1}-\sqrt{2n-1}}{\sqrt{4n^2-1}}$ without integral test?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How would you study this series *without the integral test.* I know it is a telescoping series, but I can't get to the telescoping part 
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{\sqrt{2n+1}-\sqrt{2n-1}}{\sqrt{4n^2-1}}.$$

Comment: $4n^2 - 1 = (2n + 1)(2n - 1)$

Comment: $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\cdot 1-1}}=\large 1.$$

Comment: What does it mean to "solve" a series? Prove convergence or divergence? Find the value? Because you mention the integral test, I think it is the former, but the telescoping part suggests the latter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint. We have that for $N\geq 1$,
$$\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\sqrt{2n+1}-\sqrt{2n-1}}{\sqrt{4n^2-1}}=
\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-1}}-\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}\\
=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-1}}-\sum_{n=2}^{N+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-1}}=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2(N+1)-1}}.$$

Comment: thanks, although I'm not sure how you got the to the 1 over equality, that's my dilemma.

Comment: @John 1 is the first term of the sum $\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-1}}$.

Comment: the first step is to use partial fractions decomposition, but my issue is that I don't know how you used that in this case, how you got to 1/sqrt(2n-1) - 1/sqrt(2n+1), any clue?

Comment: No need of  partial fractions decomposition. Use the fact that $\sqrt{4n^2-1}=\sqrt{2n-1}\sqrt{2n+1}$$. Then $$\frac{\sqrt{2n+1}}{\sqrt{4n^2-1}}=\frac{\sqrt{2n+1}}{\sqrt{2n-1}\sqrt{2n+1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-1}}$. The other term is obtained in a similar way..

Answer (score 1):

An idea (fill in details and justifications):

$$\frac{\sqrt{2n+1}-\sqrt{2n-1}}{\sqrt{4n^2-1}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2n+1}+\sqrt{2n-1}}{\sqrt{2n+1}+\sqrt{2n-1}}=$$

$$=\frac{2}{\sqrt{4n^2-1}\left(\sqrt{2n+1}+\sqrt{2n-1}\right)}\le\frac2{2n\sqrt{2n+1}}\le\frac2{2\sqrt2\,n^{3/2}}$$

Comment: this only shows convergence... you want to compute the actual sum

Comment: @ILoveMath Perhaps you're right, yet the question mentioned "how to solve this *without the integral test*, implying it wants to know only, or mainly, about its divergence/convergence . Anyway, the OP now has two options.

Comment: solve = find the sum. it is obiovusly convergente. perhaps you misread the question

Comment: @ilove That is **your** interpretation. You're cordially invited yo add your own answer.

Comment: not my interpretation it is reality

Comment: I think you misread the question